# Sticky footer over content using bootstrap 3 needs to be responsive

Tags: responsive-design, sticky-footer

I am using Bootstrap 3 with the following sticky footer from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

I set the `#footer` to `min-height: 420px;` so it will work responsively and adapt to narrow width and expand in height and stack the column boxes. This works just fine.

But when setting a min-height the footer will cover the content in top of it.

Is there a solution to this so the footer will be "pressed" down?

Answer (score 0):

This feature works by also setting a bottom margin on the `body` to offset the size of the footer.

For instance, sticky-footer.css contains:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

You'll need to adjust it to the `height` of your `#footer`.

Comment: That then would not be very responsive